# Spring Boot 2.5.4 + Jersey + JSF

Tags: spring-boot, jsf-2.2, spring-jersey

I built a spring boot + project with rest jersey jax-rs and some GUI's with JSF.
It's working, but every time I start the project an error log is generated, I tried to look for what it would be but I couldn't.
Can someone help me remove this and start the project without errors?

Here's my pom:

```
<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>joinfaces-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${joinfaces.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
<!-- Boot -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- Groovy -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!--JSF -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.joinfaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.20</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.20</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Jersey -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
</dependency>
<!-- Swagger Proprietario -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2</artifactId>
    <version>${swagger}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs2-servlet-initializer</artifactId>
    <version>${swagger}</version>
</dependency>
<!-- Testes -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Here is the start log with the error:

```
 .   ____          _            __ _ _
     /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
    ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
     \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
      '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
     =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
     :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.5.4)
    
    2021-09-30 10:36:09.385  INFO 23368 --- [  restartedMain] c.u.s.MicroServicoUniprimeApplication    : Starting MicroServicoUniprimeApplication using Java 11.0.4 on SUP62 with PID 23368 (D:\workspaces\intellij\projetos-spring-boot\micro-boot\target\classes started by fsilva in D:\workspaces\intellij\projetos-spring-boot\micro-boot)
    2021-09-30 10:36:09.387  INFO 23368 --- [  restartedMain] c.u.s.MicroServicoUniprimeApplication    : The following profiles are active: prod
    2021-09-30 10:36:09.426  INFO 23368 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls    : The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\fsilva\.m2\repository\org\glassfish\hk2\hk2\2.6.1\hk2-2.6.1.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/fsilva/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.6.1/hk2-utils.jar,file:/C:/Users/fsilva/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.6.1/jakarta.annotation-api.jar,file:/C:/Users/fsilva/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.6.1/jakarta.inject.jar,file:/C:/Users/fsilva/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.6.1/hk2-api.jar,file:/C:/Users/fsilva/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.6.1/aopalliance-repackaged.jar,file:/C:/Users/fsilva/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.6.1/hk2-core.jar,file:/C:/Users/fsilva/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.6.1/hk2-locator.jar,file:/C:/Users/fsilva/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.6.1/javassist.jar,file:/C:/Users/fsilva/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.6.1/hk2-runlevel.jar,file:/C:/Users/fsilva/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.6.1/class-model.jar,file:/C:/Users/fsilva/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.6.1/asm.jar,file:/C:/Users/fsilva/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.6.1/asm-analysis.jar,file:/C:/Users/fsilva/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.6.1/asm-commons.jar,file:/C:/Users/fsilva/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.6.1/asm-tree.jar,file:/C:/Users/fsilva/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.6.1/asm-util.jar
    2021-09-30 10:36:09.427  INFO 23368 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
    2021-09-30 10:36:09.427  INFO 23368 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
    2021-09-30 10:36:10.096  INFO 23368 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.joinfaces.autoconfigure.javaxfaces.JsfBeansAutoConfiguration$Jsf2_3AutoConfiguration' of type [org.joinfaces.autoconfigure.javaxfaces.JsfBeansAutoConfiguration$Jsf2_3AutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2021-09-30 10:36:10.098  INFO 23368 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.joinfaces.autoconfigure.javaxfaces.JsfBeansAutoConfiguration' of type [org.joinfaces.autoconfigure.javaxfaces.JsfBeansAutoConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2021-09-30 10:36:10.286  INFO 23368 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8085 (http)
    2021-09-30 10:36:10.293  INFO 23368 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
    2021-09-30 10:36:10.293  INFO 23368 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.52]
    2021-09-30 10:36:10.586  WARN 23368 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner  : Failed to scan [file:/C:/Users/fsilva/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/hk2/hk2/2.6.1/hk2-utils.jar] from classloader hierarchy
    
    java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:209) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFileUrlJar.<init>(JarFileUrlJar.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.JarFactory.newInstance(JarFactory.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:383) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.processURLs(StandardJarScanner.java:318) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.doScanClassPath(StandardJarScanner.java:282) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:233) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:104) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:83) ~[tomcat-embed-jasper-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5219) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:835) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1396) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1386) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:919) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:263) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:432) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:927) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.initialize(TomcatWebServer.java:123) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.<init>(TomcatWebServer.java:104) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getTomcatWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:450) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory.getWebServer(TomcatServletWebServerFactory.java:199) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.createWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:182) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:577) ~[spring-context-5.3.9.jar:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication$run.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47) ~[groovy-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125) ~[groovy-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:148) ~[groovy-3.0.8.jar:3.0.8]
        at com.uniprime.servico.MicroServicoUniprimeApplication.main(MicroServicoUniprimeApplication.groovy:15) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.5.4.jar:2.5.4]
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor22.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.compat.Jre9Compat.jarFileNewInstance(Jre9Compat.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.52.jar:9.0.52]
        ... 55 common frames omitted
```

I noticed that the error appears when I put the dependency:

```
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jersey</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Solved

Add in application.properties

```
server.tomcat.additional-tld-skip-patterns=asm.jar,class-model.jar,hk2-runlevel.jar,hk2-utils.jar,jakarta.annotation-api.jar,jakarta.inject.jar,hk2-api.jar,hk2-core.jar,hk2-locator.jar,javassist.jar
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).